# When using UNION have ORDER BY only effect 1 of the Queries

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-order-by, union

I have this query:

```
SELECT customer.CustomerID, customer.Firstname, customer.LastName, orders.DateOrdered AS LastOrdered, DATEDIFF( CURDATE( ) , MAX( orders.DateOrdered ) ) AS DaysSinseOrdered
FROM customer
LEFT JOIN orders ON customer.CustomerID = orders.CustomerID
where orders.OrdersID IS NULL 
GROUP BY customer.CustomerID, customer.FirstName, customer.LastName
UNION
SELECT customer.CustomerID, customer.Firstname, customer.LastName, orders.DateOrdered AS LastOrdered, DATEDIFF( CURDATE( ) , MAX( orders.DateOrdered ) ) AS DaysSinseOrdered
FROM customer
JOIN orders ON customer.CustomerID = orders.CustomerID
GROUP BY customer.CustomerID, customer.FirstName, customer.LastName
ORDER BY DaysSinseOrdered DESC 
LIMIT 0 , 30;
```

Which displays the info I need, however I could do this without the union.
I want this to display the NULL values first, then display the values from the second query with the ORDER BY applied. As right now it values NULL as 0, and orders all results buy the ORDER BY; but I want it at the top before the larger numbers, as in this context, its days since someone last ordered, and if you've never ordered well that should be at the top in my books.

Many thanks for any help -Tom

Comment: This is behavior as expected. ``UNION`` joins two result sets, so the ``ORDER`` is per ``SELECT`` statement

Comment: See http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/union.html specifically what happens with ``ORDER``

Answer (score 0):

You don't actually need a `UNION` to order the null values first. You just need to change your query to `ORDER BY` first by them:

```
SELECT customer.CustomerID, customer.Firstname, customer.LastName, orders.DateOrdered AS LastOrdered, DATEDIFF( CURDATE( ) , MAX( orders.DateOrdered ) ) AS DaysSinseOrdered
FROM customer
JOIN orders ON customer.CustomerID = orders.CustomerID
GROUP BY customer.CustomerID, customer.FirstName, customer.LastName
ORDER BY orders.OrdersID IS NULL DESC, DaysSinseOrdered DESC
LIMIT 0, 30
```

So this query will order the null values first and then the non-null values. Then, it will keep `DaysSinseOrdered DESC` as a second level order-